# Debugging in MPLAB PIC32 using real ice

Tags: c, exception

I am running MPLAB X for PIC32 and have the watch window open for looking at a variable `updateMemory` (static and uninitiated). 
I am trying to see where a variable is set in Initialized to 0 in the code but even before I start to run my code (i.e When I reset the processor from MPLAB) the value is already set to 0. With this value set to zero i get an exception fault and I cant seem to figure out in code how or why it gets there. Only thing I know for sure is that its caused by the condition when `updateMemory` is `0x0000` in my program.

```
void _general_exception_handler (unsigned WhoCaused, unsigned status)
{
   RCON = RCON_EXCEPTION;

   // Point of No return.
   Kernel_Reset();
}
```

I don't even initialize the variable value in my code anywhere and can't find any location where it could be getting set to 0. Even before my program starts the value is magically initialized to 0.

Is it normal for a value is memory for the particular location is always 0 and so when you reset it ALWAYS is 0?

Comment: if the variable is global it will be initialised by the startup functions.

Comment: The uninitialized variables goes to `.bss` section of the memory in RAM and the startup code of the microcontroller zeroes out the `.bss`. So, yes it is normal for a variable at particular location to be always zero.

Comment: @Peter. Do Globals get initialized to 0 or any arbitrary value in memory. Like clockwork this variable is always 0 from get go. @ Gaurav. Is there a way to identify the `.bss` section of the memory.

Comment: Yes, you can! You need to find out the linker script file, for `gcc` the linker script file has extension `*.ld` (__I Don't know the extension of linker script for MPLAB__) and in that linker script you can find out which memory address region is assigned for `*.bss`.

Comment: If they are placed in another segment than .bss not. It is random depending on how the reset is performed by the hardware. If the hardware reset resets the RAM yes, if the initial value (after the hardware reset) of the particular location is set to zero by the hardware -yes, but otherwise unless you write your own startup routines and linker script - no

Comment: All your comments makes sense. Confirmed that particular variable in question in this case `updateMemory` is a local static variable (in file Program.c, as opposed to a static inside a function, not that it makes diff) so it its stored in `.bss` section and init to 0 be default.